# Graphing the amount of time a function takes

Tags: graphics, timing

I know I can find out the amount of time a function takes to run like this:

```
In:=  function1[100] //Timing
Out:= {0.043334, Null}
```

How can I graph this over a set of 10 or 20 parameters (which are increasingly large), in order to get an idea of how the function scales?

Comment: Did you mean to write `function1[100]`?

Comment: yes. New to mathematica - not used to square brackets. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't the most exciting example but I hope it helps.

Use `AbsoluteTiming` to time the function and use `Table` to iterate over a set of values. We're simply going to time the `Pause` function which just waits `x` seconds, in this case `x^2`. The values will be stored as `list`. `First` gives us the first element of the output of `AbsoluteTiming` which is the time taken.

```
list = Table[First[AbsoluteTiming[Pause[x^2]]], {x, 0, 0.1, 0.01}];
```

Then we'll plot it with `ListPlot`

```
ListPlot[list]
```

[image: Mathematica graphic]